# codeigniter email function smtp error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

i have been using codeigniter email function to send my emails i got an warnings

config file of email is:

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['newline'] = '\r\n';
$config['smtp_host']='ssl:server address';
$config['smtp_user']='noreply@some.com';
$config['smtp_pass']='iamnotreplying';
$config['smtp_port']=465;
```

i got an warning saying

```
Warning: fwrite() [function.fwrite]: SSL: Connection reset by peer in /home/.../public_html/.../system/libraries/Email.php on line 1846
Warning: fwrite() [function.fwrite]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write retry in /home/../public_html/.../system/libraries/Email.php on line 1846
```

what could be wrong in my config of email file.

Thanks in advance
amith

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this with the config.

```
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
```

Comment: default port with 25 i tried but same warning , have other ? if that ssl://server.com is removed warnings are not their,but i'm not getting any mails from that , if that could be our server warning or what i really get confused> pls tell me?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a function like this to send email.

```
function sendEmail($email) {

        // parameters of your mail server and how to send your email
        $config = array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'sender@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'sender',
            'mailtype' => 'html'
        );

        // recipient, sender, subject, and you message

        $to = $email;
        $from = "sender@gmail.com";
        $subject = "subject";
        $message = "message body";

        // load the email library that provided by CI
        $this->ci->load->library('email', $config);
        // this will bind your attributes to email library
        $this->ci->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->ci->email->from($from, 'sender');
        $this->ci->email->to($to);
        $this->ci->email->subject($subject);
        $this->ci->email->message($message);

        // send your email. if it produce an error it will return 'Fail to send your email!'
        if ($this->ci->email->send()) {                
            return "Email was sent successfully!";
        } else {
            return "Fail to send your email";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use PHPMailer, is so easy and powerfull tool.

Here, explain how to use this:
http://phpsblog.agustinvillalba.com/phpmailer-codeigniter/

Comment: If you have found a solution for the reported problem then post it. If you just want to recommend another library for the same functionality explain at least why you shouldn't use the other one.